# How to validate Extract Autopopulate value from text field using webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have Zipcode input box , once I entered Zipcode , the state and city input boxes are auto populating with the relevant data. how to capture and validate those State and city input box value enter image description heres using Selenium [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoJaA.png)Webdriver ?

Comment: could you display what did you did already?

Comment: you need to post HTML code of your fields here .. well you just need to find the element and use gettext to get the data .. then your can use asserts for validations

Comment: I have added few images . I hope that might be helpfull resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Only thing here is you need to use getText() to retrieve text from any specified location and can verify by assertions. Lets say id of state field is 'state', then

```
 String populatedState=driver.findElement(By.id("state")).getText();

 Assert.assertEquals(populatedState, "expected state here");
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Hi, i think you updated question with HTML code after this answer. Actually there is no text in HTML code. So above code does not work in this situation.. i will look for another way